# kendo treeview with new data source

Tags: json, treeview, kendo-ui, datasource

Ok, so I have this situation here:

A CSHTML view with a kendo tree in it:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
.Name("treeview")
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataSource(d => d.Read(r => r.Action("WorkedHours", "TaskManager")))
.Events(e => e.Select("onSelect"))
)
```

to the right of that there is a kendo grid. and above the tree there is a (kendo) dropdown list to select a user.

this is the controller method called by the tree:

```
 public JsonResult WorkedHours(uint? id)
    {
        DocObjectArray docObjects = null;
        if (id == null)
        {
            // get root elements
            var loggedInUserRef = OmanagerUtils.GetInstance().LoggedInUser;
            if (loggedInUserRef != null && loggedInUserRef.GetObject() != null && loggedInUserRef.GetObject().SubObjects != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < loggedInUserRef.GetObject().SubObjects.GetLength(); i++)
                {
                    var item = loggedInUserRef.GetObject().SubObjects.GetAt(i);
                    if (item.ToString() == TaskManagerConstants.UserWorkHours)
                    {
                        docObjects = item.TreeSubObjects;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // get sub objects of a root object
            var rootObj = new DocObjectRef((int)id);
            docObjects = rootObj.GetObject().TreeSubObjects;
        }
        var returnDocObjects = new List<OmanagerItem>();

        for (int i = 0; i < docObjects.GetLength(); i++)
        {
            var item = docObjects.GetAt(i);
            var hasChildren = true;
            if (item.TreeSubObjects == null)
            {
                hasChildren = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (item.TreeSubObjects.GetLength() == 0)
                {
                    hasChildren = false;
                }
            }
            var listItem = new OmanagerItem
            {
                hasChildren = hasChildren,
                id = item.GetOID(),
                Name = item.ToString()
            };
            returnDocObjects.Add(listItem);
        }
        return Json(returnDocObjects, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

now, the problem is that i have to be able to select a user from the dropdown list and refresh the tree with this new data.

```
$("#employee").kendoDropDownList({
                change: function () {
                    var postdata = {
                        id:$("#employee").val()
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "TaskManager/WorkedHours",
                        cache: false,
                        type: "POST",
                        data: postdata,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView").setDataSource(data);
                        },
                    });
                }
            });
```

the problem is what do i do with this data? because my attempt did not really work.

many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OutputCache attribute on WorkedHours action:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")]
public JsonResult WorkedHours(uint? id)
{
 // rest of method
}
```

It helped in my case :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this little snippet is of any help to you.
Similar to your code in the change event of my dropdown I'm calling a function that will change the request data of my TreeView DataSource.

After changing it, it calls the `read()` handler of the datasource so it re-reads the data:

```
function loadTreeViewData() {
    var employee = $('#employee').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
    WorkedHoursDataSource.transport.options.read.data = {Employee_Id:employee.id};

    WorkedHoursDataSource.read();
}
```